# Finding if a circle is inside another circle

Tags: java, math

I'm having a bit of trouble. I have an assignment that requires me to find if a second circle is overlapping, inside, or neither a second circle. However, I am having trouble checking for overlapping and if the second circle is inside the first.

(variables used are x1, x2, y1, y2, r1, r2, distance)

Here's what I have:

```
if (distance > (r1 + r2)) {
        // No overlap
        System.out.println("Circle2 does not overlap Circle1");
    } else if (distance <= Math.abs(r1 + r2)) {
        // Overlap
        System.out.println("Circle2 overlaps Circle1");
    } else if ((distance <= Math.abs(r1 - r2)) {
        // Inside
        System.out.println("Circle2 is inside Circle1");
}
```

I fear the problem is with the overlapping and inside checks, but I cannot figure out how to properly set it up so I can reliably check if the second circle is inside the first.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated as I've tried multiple approaches but the solution simply escapes me every time.

Comment: First - what is distance? Is it the distance between the centers of the circles? Second - might it help to figure out which radius is greater?

Comment: All of the variables are entered by the user. Yes, the distance is the distance between the two centers of the two circles with the distance formula.

Comment: I just googled to find about this problem and found this  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/how-to-find-out-if-two-circles-intersect-each-other

Comment: I think the distance between the centres is key.... and the order you do the test...

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this will help quite a bit.

Comment: That's not all the states that a circle could be in. Circle A could be inside circle B, or circle B could be inside Circle A, or they could be the same circle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you just need to check for inside before overlap as distance for inside is <= distance for overlap

```
if (distance > (r1 + r2)) 
{
    // No overlap
    System.out.println("Circle2 does not overlap Circle1");
}
else if ((distance <= Math.abs(r1 - r2)) 
{
    // Inside
    System.out.println("Circle2 is inside Circle1");
}
else              // if (distance <= r1 + r2)
{
   // Overlap
   System.out.println("Circle2 overlaps Circle1");
}
```

answer modified as per Chris's comments

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. I tried this once before, but I think I ordered it wrong with the wrong comparisons.

Thanks again.

Comment: You have unnecessary code in there. Since r1 and r2 are both >0 (I assume since they are radiuses) then r1+r2 doesn't need the abs call around it. If you then compare this check to your first one then you will note that it will always be try if the first was false so you can skip the condition and make the last one a plain else.

Comment: I know that I just rearranged the code in the original question, buts its a good point to make, I'll put a comment it.

Comment: What you have done indicates that that is the correct test though which it is not. If you have the correct test it doesn't matter which order you do them in. The only reason your answer works is because your final test happens to always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 9):

This problem is probably easiest worked out visually first and then the code written. You look like you've got the right logic for not inside and fully inside.

The easy way to deal with this is that if they are not fully inside and not fully outside then they must be overlapping. This is certainly how I would code it. The maths is a little trickier than the other two.

```
if (distance > (r1 + r2)) {
    // No overlap
    System.out.println("Circle2 does not overlap Circle1");
} else if ((distance <= Math.abs(r1 - r2)) {
    // Inside
    System.out.println("Circle2 is inside Circle1");
{ else {
    // Overlap
    System.out.println("Circle2 overlaps Circle1");
}
```

The actual condition is:

`r2>r1-d` and `r2 < r1+d`

By symmetery we don't need to do both ways round (if you swap r2 and r1 in both and do a bit of rearranging you get teh same pair of equations out).

Its easiest to just leave this in the "else" category though rather than coding for it unless you need to for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the sum of distance and smaller radius is less than the other radius, smaller circle should be inside the bigger one.

Comment: Only if the centers are close enough to each other, if they aren't, you might have overlapping or not even overlapping circles.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau. Sorry, but this is not true. Well, at least, as long the *distance* means the distance between the both centers. If the centers are far enough that the circles intersect, then we may have two cases: a) the center of one circle is within the other => d+r2 > r1 || d+r1 > r2 ; or b) no circle center is within the other circle => d>r1 || d>r2 already.

Answer (score 2):

Edit for obviousness by comment proxy:

The distance between to points in space are described by pythagoras:

```
  distance = sqrt( travelled_x_squared + travelled_y_squared );
```

Which of course translates to code as

```
  distance = Math.sqrt(  (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2) );
```

The distance is at contact at r1 + r2.

Before edit clues:
You need the angle between the circles.

Then you compute the distance from circle1 to circle 2. If it is less than radii1 + radii2 you are inside.

atan2 might be a function of interest.

Or just go with the pythagorean distance directly.

Comment: The angles are totally irrelevant. You can always just consider the line through the two centers and the distances along those lines (distance, r1, r2).

Comment: @Chris Yes that is the pythagorean distance.

Comment: I'm not sure that explains why you think you need angles. You are only going to complicate things and atan2 is really not of interest for this problem and is going to lead you down a path to a wrong solution...

Comment: @Chris I was just trying to be helpful with a multitude of suggestions tagged Java, math and homework. All avenues have their own rewards, none end in a wrong solution. I have no idea why you wrote that.

Comment: I don't believe any solution that can be considered right would use trig functions. I'm not even sure you need the xn,yn since we are given the distance between the two points. If you start using the angle you are most likely going to do something that can be vastly simplified. eg even assuming we don't have distance already you can work out the angle from the given x and y using arctan and then use sin/cos to work out the distance between the two points but it would still not be a good way to do it (and thus I'd say wrong) given you could just use pythagoras's theorem to do it (as you did).

Answer (score 2):

You're very nearly there. It's just the order of the conditions that's wrong.

```
if (distance > (r1 + r2)) {
        // No overlap
        System.out.println("Circle2 does not overlap Circle1");
    } else if ((distance <= Math.abs(r1 - r2)) {
        // Inside
        System.out.println("Circle2 is inside Circle1");
    } else {
        // Overlap
        System.out.println("Circle2 overlaps Circle1");
}
```

Checking the 'inside' case after the 'non-overlapping' case ensures it won't be accidentally considered an overlap. Then all the rest must be overlaps.

Comment: You and Dampsquid were right on the money.

I tried this before, but I goofed the comparisons so it came back wrong every time.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple task,

take the sum of the radius of two circle. say r1+ r2 .
Now find the distance between center of two circle which is sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
`if r1+r2 = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) they just touch each other.
if r1+r2 > sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) the circle overlaps(intersect)
if r1+ r2 < sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2) the circle doesnot intersect`

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
   *
   * @param values { x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1 }
   * @return true if circles is intersected
   */
  public static boolean isCircleIntersect(double... values)
  {
    /* check using mathematical relation: ABS(R0-R1) <= SQRT((x0-x1)^2+(y0-y1)^2) <= (R0+R1) */
    if (values.length == 6)
    {
      /* get values from first circle */
      double x0 = values[0];
      double y0 = values[1];
      double r0 = values[2];
      /* get values from second circle */
      double x1 = values[3];
      double y1 = values[4];
      double r1 = values[5];
      /* returun result */
      return (Math.abs(r0 - r1) <= Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x0 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y0 - y1), 2)))
              && (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x0 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y0 - y1), 2)) <= (r0 + r1));
    }
    else
    {
      /* return default result */
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should use the code button to format this as source code.