# Google Map Circle calculation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have two Circle in a google map with different location and radius. Both are displaying fine.

How do I calculate or know Which circle is in the another circle or not.

Please help me with some ideas so that I can take this challenge.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding if a circle is inside another circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486520/finding-if-a-circle-is-inside-another-circle)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're asking, but here's a couple of ideas.

First, this is not a programming problem; it's a mathematics problem.

Given two circles, one with a radius of `r1` and the second with a radius of `r2`. Calculate the distance between the centers of the circles (call it `d`).

Circle 2 is partially inside circle 1 if `d` is less than `r1` and `d` + `r2` is greater than `r1` or `d` is less than `r1` + `r2`.

Circle 2 is completely inside circle 1 `d` is less than `r1` and `d` + `r2` is less than `r1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually what I need, I have a website of two types of users one is advertiser and another is user, both have Demographics. advertiser can send offer by email if the advertisers location is within the users radius or Vice versa (this is main condition).